# Last entry of the eigenvector of a tri-diagonal matrix

Tags: trigonometry, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

To solve the Laplace's equation using finite element approach, we need to find the eigenvector of a $n\times n$ tri-diagonal matrix. (sorry for using matlab notation)
$$A=h^{-2}[2,-1,0,\dots;-1,2,-1,0,\dots;0,-1,2,-1,0,\dots;\dots;0,\dots,0,-1,2]$$
where $h=1/(n+1)$. It turns out that the $k$-th eigenvector $\vec{u}_k$is a vector of sine function of which the $j$-th element is $\sin(jk\pi h)$.

I can show that for $1<k<n$, the elements $1,\dots,(n-1)$ satisfies $A\vec{u}_k=\lambda\vec{u}_k$. But I got some problems in showing the $n$-th element of the vector.

The $n$-th element of $A\vec{u}_k$ is $h^{-2}[-\sin((n-1)k\pi h)+2\sin(nk\pi h)]$. Can someone show me how to prove that this entry is equal to $2h^{-2}\sin(nk\pi h)[1-\cos(k\pi h)]$, which is essentially to show $\sin((n-1)k\pi h)=2\sin(nk\pi h)\cos(k\pi h)$.

Comment: Look up product-to-sum formulas and remember that $h=1/(n+1)$ and that $sin(k\pi)=0$.

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware of $h=1/(n+1)$. Please answer it below so that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a product-to-sum formula which states the following.
$$\sin u\cos v= \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(u+v)+\sin(u-v)\right)$$
Using this formula, we get the foolowing relation.
\begin{equation} 2\sin(nk\pi h)\cos(k\pi h)=\sin((n+1)k\pi h)+\sin((n-1)k\pi h)\end{equation}
But as you state in your question above, $h=1/(n+1)$. Since $\sin(k\pi)=0$, the above reduces to the needed relation.

Answer (score 0):

$2\sin{(nk\pi h)}\cos{(k\pi h)}=\sin{\bigl((n+1)k\pi h\bigr)}+\sin{\bigl((n-1)k\pi h\bigr)}=\sin{\bigl((n-1)k\pi h\bigr)}$. It is just the use of trigonometric formulas.